# ChunkDB to handle high traffic JSON web service? Alternatives?

Tags: database, api, http, json

I am designing a high volume web service which will rely on a central database containing objects of a single JSON type. Currently I am considering using ChunkDB to store the objects and retrieve the objects using views (RESTful API). Some of the views may be complex. The amount of data stored in the database will be limited as objects will 'expire'.

Is a sensible approach to the problem? What are the other options?

Comment: Url for ChunkDB?  The 4th hit on google for it is this question.  Not exactly confidence building.  And what is 'high volume' to you?  Is there some *technical* reason you cant or shouldnt use a more traditional database (be it SQL or NoSQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDb is a good candidate -- it is a Json-based document database with a HTTP interface, so you could serve directly out of that application.

You could also look at using something like node.js with whatever backing database you can make work. It scales really, really well by design.